# save the file with loop index in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to save some variables in matlab program like

```
for i =1:10
x(i)=randn()*5; 
save(i,x(i));
end
```

At every iteration 'i' I want it save the values of x(i), but matlab gives me the error "Error using save Must be a string scalar or character vector." How can I solve this

Comment: Can you provide some actual code that you've written to try and solve your problem? That will make it much easier to understand what you're asking, and easier to provide a fix to your problem. As it stands your question is vague, and we can't know what you're trying to do.

Comment: https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/236354-saving-mat-files-in-a-for-loop

Comment: Into what do you want to save `x(i)`? Files or columns/rows of another variable?